# Solution of Initial Value Problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the given initial value problem:

$(x+y)^2dx+(2xy+x^2-9)dy=0$ and $y(1)=1$

I thought one way is to to put $x=X+h$ and $y=Y+k$ to make the equation homogeneous but it seems a bit complicated. Can anyone suggest any smarter way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the method of exact equations ([here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/first-order-differential-equations/exact-equations/v/exact-equations-intuition-1-proofy), [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/first-order-differential-equations/exact-equations/v/exact-equations-intuition-2-proofy), and [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/first-order-differential-equations/exact-equations/v/exact-equations-example-1).)

The work:$$M = x^2+2xy+y^2\text{ and }N=2xy+x^2-9$$ $$\int x^2+2xy+y^2\ dx=\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^2y}{2}+xy^2+f(y)$$ $$\frac{\partial(\frac{x^3}{3}+x^2y+xy^2+f(y))}{\partial y}=x^2+2xy+f'(y)$$ $$f'(y)=-9$$ $$f(y) = -9y$$ $$\Psi(x, y) = \frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^2y}{2}+xy^2-9y$$And the implicit solution:$$\frac{x^3}{3}+x^2y+xy^2-9y=C$$